# Add new virtual directory under IIS6 Default Web Site and change the .net Framework to 4.0

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, iis-6

I have windows 2003 and IIS6. I have a WCF service written in .net 4.0. 
Default web site under IIS6 runs under .net 2.0. How can I add new virtual directory that will point to my wcf service which will be running under .net 4.0? Currently under Default web sites there are 3 web sites running. I know I can simply add new web site but then I will have to run it using different port, isn't right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to install .Net 4.0 in IIS 6. You can do this with the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). Once this is done you can set the framework version of the virtual directory from the ASP.NET tab on the virtual directory property sheet. You may also need to enable ASP.NET 4.0 under [Web Service Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596ff388-bc4c-472f-b029-aea2b0418bea.mspx?mfr=true).